# Unexpected behaviour for custom type returned from a function

Tags: postgresql, syntax, types, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2

I have created a custom type

```
CREATE TYPE rc_test_type AS (a1 bigint);
```

and a function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.rc_test_type_function(test_table character varying, dummy integer)
  RETURNS rc_test_type AS
$BODY$ 
    DECLARE
    ret rc_test_type;
    query  text;
    BEGIN
    query := 'SELECT count(*) from '  || test_table    ;
    EXECUTE query into ret.a1;  
    RETURN ret;
END $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

If I run

```
SELECT * FROM rc_test_type_function('some_table', 1);
```

I get

```
"a1"
1389
```

So far so good.

If I run

```
SELECT p FROM (SELECT rc_test_type_function('some_table', s.step) AS p 
FROM  some_other_table s) foo;
```

I get

```
"p"
"(1389)"
"(1389)"
```

since 'some_other_table' has just two records. Fine.

But then if I try

```
SELECT p.a1 FROM (select rc_test_type_function('some_table', s.step) AS p
FROM some_other_table s) foo;
```

I get the error

> missing FROM-clause entry in subquery for table »p«

which I find strange since the subquery has not changed.

Two questions:

1. Can anyone explain what's going on?
2. How do I extract the field value `a1` from the returned array?

Comment: +1 Very nice question with all the information required. Good job for newcomer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **parentheses** around the **composite type**:

```
SELECT (p).a1
FROM   (SELECT rc_test_type_function('some_table', s.step) AS p
        FROM   some_other_table s
       ) foo;
```

Even though your type has just a single column is still a composite type - with its own column name. Doesn't make a lot of sense, but that's how you built it.
(You might want to just use a simple type or maybe a [`DOMAIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createdomain.html) instead.)

Quoting [the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#FIELD-SELECTION):

> `(compositecol).somefield`
>   `(mytable.compositecol).somefield`
>
> The parentheses are required here to show that `compositecol` is a column name not a
>   a table name, or that `mytable` is a table name not a schema name in the second case.

#### Proper function

Omitting the part with the composite type, your function would be *safer, simpler and faster* this way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(test_table varchar, dummy int, OUT p bigint)
  AS
$func$ 
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('SELECT count(*) from %I', test_table)  -- !avoid SQLi!
   INTO p;  
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

- Avoid SQL injection with dynamic SQL!
- An [`OUT` parameter](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html) simplifies the syntax in this case. You don't need a `DECLARE` clause at all, and no `RETURN` either

#### Even better

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(test_table regclass, dummy int, OUT p bigint)
  AS
$func$ 
BEGIN
   EXECUTE 'SELECT count(*) from ' || test_table
   INTO p;  
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

- By using the [object identifier `regclass`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html) this would also work with schema-qualified table names. And SQLi is *not possible* to begin with. The function would fail immediately if the table name is illegal and it is quoted automatically when converted to `text` automatically.